# ¿Cómo muestro una información depende del usuario que Inicie sesión en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cuenta-usuario, visualización-de-datos

Estoy entrando en este mundo poco a poco y quiero saber alguna forma de hacer esto para un proyecto propio y probar! Mi pregunta es como puedo a partir de un usuario registrado en PHP con un PDO pueda mostrarme un dato pero otra persona logueada tenga otros datos distintos tipo:

USUARIO 1:

- Camara: Canon
- Marca Tripode: Kipsta

USUARIO 2:

- Camara Nikon
- Marca tripode: Raya

Quiero crear esto para luego mostrarlo en pantalla a modo de info. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo creando una tabla donde le pases el id del usuario y los datos de la camara, tripode, etc y a la hora de mostrarlo compruebas que el id insertado en la tabla es igual al id de la sesión creada (id del usuario logeado)

Comment: Pero en todo caso, habría que unir base de datos? O eso directamente lo pongo como parámetros de la propia base de datos de usuario?? Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Claro, debes crear una base de datos.

Comment: Pero la cuestión es que, yo he creado un formulario en donde he creado una base de datos y una tabla de usuarios, pero ahora, cuando alguien se registra no consigo que se cree otra tabla cuando alguien se registra, no sé si me explico... Alguien se registra y contrata algo y en su DASHBOAR le aparece que ha contratado algo, pero otro usuario se registra y no contrata nada no quiero que le aparezca nada... Gracias por su ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Por que la tabla no la creas desde php, mírate un tutorial sobre php y mysql ya que estoy es algo básico.

Comment: En pocas palabras, debes crear una base de datos con dos tablas, una para los usuarios y otra para los datos y relacionarlas

Comment: Entiendo... pero el problema es que no me crea una tabla cuando un usuario se registra, pero muchas gracias por tu aportación y ayuda :D

Comment: Te refieres a que no se guarda ningún registro cuando un usuario de registra? Sin ver nada de código es más difícil de solucionar.